# Windows Phone: Add custom Account

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

is it possible to create a custom account (similar to Microsoft Account,Facebook, Twitter, ...) in Windows Phone so that a user can setup an account of my Custom Type and then can sync data and so on.

It's something similar to using a SyncAdapter in Android.

can I achieve this in Windows Phone ? what are the APIs to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to setup your own account type.

But in Windows Phone 8 your application can add its own contacts to People hub. Here is basic samples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207024(v=vs.105).aspx

And from this book you can get more details:

[Windows Phone 8 Development Internals](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145373342.do)